# nginx: how to disable access_log for ($http_status == 200)

Tags: nginx, http-status-code

Is there any way to disable `access_log` for 200 HTTP response code? I tried using conditions but it seems `access_log` directive is not allowed in an `if` block. I tried this:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log;

if ($http_status == 200){
    access_log off;   # <---------
}
```

but it is not valid

```
# nginx -t    
nginx: [emerg] "access_log" directive is not allowed here ...
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In the following example, the requests with response codes 2xx will not be logged:

map $status $loggable {
    ~^[2]  0;
    default 1;
}

access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log combined if=$loggable;

Src : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log

Comment: @mightyteja thanks a lot. that worked fine. but why did you commented instead of posting an answer?

Comment: You are welcome. I just dont want to flood the question if its not the right one. Moreover it will stay as a troubleshooting step. Updated it as answer. If the answer does solve your query, please accept the answer so that other who view the thread later would find it useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try

```
map $status $loggable
{ 
    ~^[2] 0; 
    default 1; 
} 

access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log combined if=$loggable;
```

which causes requests with response codes 2xx not to be logged.

[ngx_http_log_module documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log)